# ActionScript Local X And Y Coordinates Of Display Object?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, coordinates

i'm trying to trace the x and y coordinates from within a sprite.  i've added a rectangle to the stage:

```
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200);
addChild(rect);
rect.x = rect.y = 100;
```

adding a Mouse_Move event to the rect, i can trace mouseX and mouseY to receive the coordinates of the stage while moving over the rect, but how do i get the local x and y coordinates?  so if i mouse over the very top left of the rect sprite, the mouseX and mouseY return 10 as the global coordinates, but how do i make it return 0 and the local coordinates of the sprite?

i assumed localX and localY was what i was looking for, but this doesn't work:

```
function mouseOverTraceCoords(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
trace(mouseX, mouseY, evt.localX, evt.localY);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you have designed your Rectangle class,
if you have done something like this:

```
class Rect1 extends Sprite {
    public function Rect1(x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number) {
        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.beginFill(0xff0000, 0.5);
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        g.endFill();
    }
}
```

your local coordinate will be at `0,0` but you drawing start at `x,y` so when you are getting the `localx, localY` you will obtain `x,y` and not `0,0`.

But if your class is designed as something like that :

```
class Rect2 extends Sprite {
    public function Rect2(x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number) {
        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.beginFill(0xff0000, 0.5);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.endFill();

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

then your drawing start at `0,0` and your object is moved at `x,y` so the `localX` and `localY` from the `MouseEvent` will be ok.

**Edit:**
To get the local coordinate you can try using getBounds :

```
function mouseOverTraceCoords(evt:MouseEvent):void {
 var dob:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(evt.target);
 var bnds:flash.geom.Rectangle = getBounds(dob.parent);
 var localX:Number=e.localX - bnds.x + dob.x;
 var localY:Number=e.localY - bnds.y + dob.y;

 trace(mouseX, mouseY, evt.localX, evt.localY, localX, localY);
}
```

Comment: it's designed as in your first example.  so how can i receive local coordinates from that?  the rect sprite is draggable, so that's why i can't assign it's position as in  your second example.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Ok i have edited my answer see if it works in your app.

Comment: thanks.  it turned out to be a lot easier than i was anticipating.  i simply had to subtract evt.localX from getRect(this).x to receive the local coordinates.  it took me far too long to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [globalToLocal](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do any transformations at all *, your Rectangle will have two properties called `mouseX` and `mouseY` which contain the local coordinates of the mouse.

If you're drawing your graphics offset within the rectangle, the coordinate system will not consider this, it's a better idea to offset the entire rectangle instead.

** assuming your Rectangle class is a subclass of DisplayObject, which I'd assume since you've got it on the stage.*

Comment: when i call rect.mouseX and rect.mouseY, i get the same coordinates as the stage's mouseX and mouseY

Comment: i mean, if i add the rect in the middle of the stage, so it's not located at X=0, Y=0, which would return the same coordinates, they are still the same.